# NGINX proxy pass for a WordPress docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, wordpress

- A WordPress container is running and it's successfully reachable via
  http://localhost:8000
- The requirement is WordPress site should be
  accessible via http://localhost/site-a
- NGINX proxy is available
  separately and I tried with the following proxy pass configuration,
  but it doesn't work and I get "Too many redirects" error.

```
    location /site-a {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; # change the port here
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

How can I get done my requirement?

Comment: Have you configured the URL in WordPress properly?

Comment: Still I can't even get the installation wizard

Answer (score 0):

You add following lines to `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', '<URL>' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', '<URL>' );
```

where URL is the URL you use to access WordPress root.

Comment: So, I set URL as http://localhost:8000 in the wp-config.php. What happens is when I load the site via http://localhost/site-a, redirection happens to http://localhost:8000.  I need to keep http://localhost/site-a all the time. Any other suggestion or a modification for this answer ?

Comment: You need to set the URL that you use to access WordPress root, which is `http://localhost/site-a`.